# Pipe in Environment variable in fish shell doesn't execute the first command?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, pipe, fish

I want to set `fish_greeting` to `date --rfc-2822 | cowsay -f tux | lolcat` (don't judge me). When I run `date --rfc-2822 | cowsay -f tux | lolcat` interactively, I get the proper output (the date in a speech bubble above tux in rainbow colors). However, when I `set fish_greeting date --rfc-2822 | cowsay -f tux | lolcat`, I get this output:

```
 _ 
<   >
 - 
   \
    \
        .--.
       |o_o |
       |:_/ |
      //   \ \
     (|     | )
    /'\_   _/`\
    \___)=(___/

date --rfc-2822
```

(in color, of course). Why isn't the first pipe working?

Comment: I don't know what fish is, but have you tried putting the complete path to date in the command? It looks like it's just echoing out the command instead of executing it

Comment: @djsmiley2k http://fishshell.com/. I tried /usr/bin/date, but that give the same output, but with /usr/bin/date at the bottom instead.

Comment: Weird, I just had a quick play with cowsay (I'm not going to install fishshell atm because no time) but got it 'working' with `cowsay $(/bin/date)`

Comment: @djsmiley2k In fish the equivalent is `cowsay (*command*)` (this works). However, I think the problem is that the first command is being echoed, not executed, because the new output is `cowsay -f tux Sun, 01 May 2016 11:55:07 -0700`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fish_greeting [can be a function](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-greeting)

```
function fish_greeting; date --rfc-2822 | cowsay -f tux | lolcat; end
```

Comment: Clarification: `fish_greeting` can be a literal string or a function. It has to be a function if you're doing things like executing a statement that includes pipes (or any external command for that matter). See *__fish_config_interactive.fish*.